# What does it mean to find all solutions on the interval?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've just started the chapter on differential equations. The textbook has this exercise:

> (...) Prove that the function $f(x)$ satisfies the differential equation $xy' - y = x\sin(x)$ on the interval $(-\infty, +\infty)$ and *find all solutions on this interval*.

What does it mean to find all solutions on the interval? Does it mean that the function that they showed is one of the solutions and I am asked to find the alternative functions that satisfy the same diff. equation?

Comment: "Does it mean... " Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have to describe a set of functions, all of which are solutions for the differential equation on the interval. Also, you have to show that if $f$ is a function that satisfies the equation then $f$ is an element of your set.